# PhpMailer send mail no error info

Tags: php

I am trying to send mail and it just brought me to blank page. The echo had not been hit and i couldn't see the error.

```
try {
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;   
    $address = "xx@gmail.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "xx");
    $mail->Subject = "Contact Form Submission | " . $name;
    $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xx@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password1234';

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
    else
        echo 'sent';
    //header("Location: contact.php?status=thanks");
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo 'error1';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'error2';
}
```

Comment: maybe there was no error to see

Comment: There may be a syntax error. Check your server logs. Also switch on PHP error reporting so that you can see the errors rather than getting a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should turn error reporting on with the following two lines on the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, have you included the SMTP class of PHPMailer, since you're sending mail through SMTP? The file "class.smtp.php" should be placed in the same directory as "class.phpmailer.php" - if that is missing, then PHPMailer will error out when it's trying to include it